# HttpSession - how to get the session.setAttribute?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, listener

I'm creating HttpSession container this way:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="userManager")
public class UserManager extends Tools
{
  /* [private variables] */
  ...
  public String login() 
  {
    /* [find user] */
    ...
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("id", user.getID());
    session.setAttribute("username", user.getName());
    ...
    System.out.println("Session id: " + session.getId());
```

And I have SessionListener which should gives me info about session created:

```
@WebListener
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener
{
  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {    
    HttpSession session = event.getSession();
    System.out.println("Session id: " + session.getId());
    System.out.println("New session: " + session.isNew());
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I get the `username` attribute?

If I'm trying it using `System.out.println("User name: " + session.getAttribute("username"))` it throws `java.lang.NullPointerException`..

Comment: so session or System.out is null

Comment: Using raw Servlet API inside JSF code is in almost all cases a code smell. In this particular case, why don't you just use a session scoped managed bean?

Comment: I don´t understand the question...? The first part of code with `FacesContext` is in session scoped managed bean. I'm gonna edit my post.. Could you tell me more?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `HttpSessionListener` interface is used to monitor when sessions are created and destroyed on the application server. The `HttpSessionEvent.getSession()` returns you a session that is newly created or destroyed (depending if it's called by `sessionCreated`/`sessionDestroyed` respectively).

If you want an existing session, you will have to get the session from the request.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true).
String username = (String)session.getAttribute("username");
```

Comment: Thank you Gentleman, you're right and the getting session from request helped me too :-)

Comment: it's just like php, but for some reason I can get through this :S I have just like this my code, and yet not working. java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:108)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
HttpSession hs = request.getSession(true);
long idUser = (long)hs.getAttribute("userid");

Comment: It will very useful to me if you say how can i create a (request) object ? ---request.getSession(true).

Answer (score 4):

The `session.getAttribute("key")` return a value of `java.lang.Object` type if given key is found. It returns null otherwise.

```
String userName=(String)session.getAttribute("username");

if(userName!=null)
{
  System.out.println("User name: " + userName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's not null now, but it returns something like `session.UserManager@1a4f43e`. Is it possible to decode the object to be able to use it like `if (userName.equeals("admin")) {}` ??

Comment: @gaffcz - Are you sure you set "String" type value to "username" key? What is the return type of user.getName() method?

Comment: The first line in this answer, is better than the official documentation. I expected it to return null in case the attribute was not found, but the documentation fails to tell me so... Thanks